# Place floating UIButton on top of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uibutton, uicollectionview

I'm desperately trying to place a UIButton on top of my UICollectionView. The goal is something like the check-in button from the new foursquare app.

My code currently looks like so:

```
UIButton *floatingButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[floatingButton setFrame:CGRectMake(320, 150, 50, 50)];
[floatingButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[self.collectionView addSubview:floatingButton];
[self.collectionView bringSubviewToFront:floatingButton];
```

The problem is the button isn't anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you probably want to add the button to the collectionView's parent view.
most likely self.view, but its hard to say for sure without seeing more code.

instead of

```
[self.collectionView addSubview:floatingButton];
```

you probably want

```
[self.view addSubview:floatingButton];
```

Comment: But I also made a silly mistake `[floatingButton setFrame:CGRectMake(320, 150, 50, 50)];`is outside of the viewing frame I had to set it to `[floatingButton setFrame:CGRectMake(150, 150, 50, 50)];`

Comment: Even with this approach (That I assume is the correct) I can't make the button touchable.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Add your button to collectionView superView, might be self.view.

```
[self.view addSubview:floatingButton];
```

and set the button as firstResponder.

```
[floatingButton becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: **superview**.addSubview(), not **view**.addSubview(). At least for Swift 4+